# Convert AVAsset to CMSampleBuffer with timestamp

Tags: ios, swift, avasset

I followed a solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66879724/how-do-you-convert-an-avasset-into-cmsamplebuffer-frames) to write a video file into a CMSampleBuffer. I want to do trajectory recognition on a given video file. Therefore VNDetectTrajectoriesRequest requires CMSampleBuffer to be timestamped. But I have no clue how to achieve that.

The code I use looks like this:

```
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "IMG_9900", ofType: "MOV") else {
    fatalError("no movie found")
}

let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
let asset :AVAsset = AVAsset(url: url)
let reader = AVAssetReader(asset: asset)
guard let track = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).last else {
    return
}
let trackOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: track, outputSettings: nil)
reader.add(trackOutput)
reader.startReading()

// Get first sample buffer
var sample = trackOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()
while sample != nil {
    print("1",sample)
    sample =  trackOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()

    let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cmSampleBuffer: sample!)
    try requestHandler.perform([request])
    print("2",sample)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure buffers have no timestamp? How did you check that?

Comment: Good point. I am not sure. I played with the code again and found out, that when I try to use sample I get an error, that it is nil. I updated the example »print("1",sample)« prints my cmsamplebuffer's content. BUT the requestHandler doesn't seem to be able to use the cmsamplebuffer and throws. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: let asset = AVAsset() is empty. Y should initialize it with some content.

Comment: True. But that is a mistake in the code snipped that I posted. Sorry. In my playground I do load a real video file. Updated the example…

Comment: make request only then read a new sample. At some point of time it may result in sample being nil before making request.